# wp_redirect hangs, but returns true

Tags: wp-redirect

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, but I can't get the wp_redirect to actually redirect the page. I enabled the wp_debug to check for "header already sent" errors, but nothing. I installed the "Better HTTP Redirects" plugin to check the response, but it says 302 found.

If I check the wp_redirect response like this, it says "redirect success". But nothing really happens in the end, no errors show up either.

```
if ( wp_redirect( admin_url( 'admin.php?page=plugin_test&success=item_saved' ) ) ) {
   echo 'redirect success'; 
} else {
   echo 'no';
}
```

I tried to add ob_start to the init, and add an action for the admin_init and call ob_start from there but both made no difference. This is a stripped down version of the code I have, but it has the same problem.

What happens in the complete code is that the user fills in a form, adds the item and it is saved to the db. After that the user is redirected and a custom msg is shown. The whole script works fine, except for the last redirect.

```
class Submit_Test {

    function __construct() {
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'init' ) );
    }

    public function init() {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'create_admin_menu' ) );    
    }

    public function create_admin_menu() {           
        add_menu_page( 'Plugin test', 'Menu', 'manage_options', 'plugin_test', array( $this, 'item_list' ) );
    }

    public function item_list() {
        if ( isset( $_REQUEST['actions'] ) ) {
            $this->add_item();
        } 

        if ( isset( $_GET['success'] ) ) {
            $this->show_success_notifications();
        }

        if ( $_GET['action']['add_item'] ) { 
            ?>
                <form method="post" action="" accept-charset="utf-8">
                    <input type="submit" name="actions" class="button-primary" value="add_item" />
                </form>
            <?php
        } else {
            ?>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://localhost/wp-latest/wp-admin/admin.php?page=plugin_test">Current Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://localhost/wp-latest/wp-admin/admin.php?page=plugin_test&action=add_item">Add Item</a></li>
                </ul>
            <?php
        }   
    }

    public function add_item() {
        if ( wp_redirect( admin_url( 'admin.php?page=plugin_test&success=item_saved' ) ) ) {
            echo 'redirect success';    
        } else {
            echo 'no';
        }

         exit();
    }

    public function show_success_notifications() {  
        echo 'yes'; 
    }   
}

new Submit_Test;
```

Any ideas on how to get the redirect to work, and what i'm doing wrong? I'm out of ideas on what could be the problem here.

Comment: your `item_list` function will certainly run after output has already started, so this does seem like a headers already sent issue.

Comment: note that headers already sent is a warning and not a fatal error, so you may have the wrong error reporting level and you're just not seeing it.

Comment: `wp_redirect()` is a pluggable function, so a plugin or a theme may have overridden it.  Try disabling all your plugins and switch to a default theme like Twenty Twelve or Twenty Thirteen, and then see if the problem persists. (Admittedly, it's a long shot, but at the very least you'll be able to eliminate your plugins as the culprit.)

Comment: Is using `header('Location: '.$newURL);` an option?

Comment: It turned out to be a "headers already sent" issue after all. I only saw the message after disabling all other plugins. 

Not exactly sure why it happens, but I found that the slideshow gallery plugin that I use (http://wordpress.org/plugins/slideshow-gallery/) is preventing the "header already sent" from appearing and the redirect from working. At least when I disable it, it works fine.

I searched in the slideshow gallery code for 'wp_redirect', to I see if it's being used or modified. But it returns no results. How else could another plugin break / prevent the wp_redirect from working?

Comment: @tijmen, to answer your question, consider `$location = apply_filters( 'wp_redirect', $location, $status );`... A plugin that adds a `wp_redirect` filter that does not behave correctly could certainly cause this issue.  I do not see this as being the case in Slideshow Gallery, but it _is_ doing something with `wp_redirect()` in the function `custom_redirect()` in slideshow-gallery.php.

Answer (score 1):

wp_redirect() does not exit automatically and should almost always be followed by exit.

Have you tried adding an exit after wp_redirect?  It could be as simple as that

Comment: Yeah, the reason dijmen is doing an `echo` after `wp_redirect` and actually seeing the output sort of proves this theory :) One should always `exit` or `die()` after a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You are hooking in too late to use wp_redirect, your code isn't being executed until the admin_menu hook fires, which is after headers have already been sent to the browser and therefore too late to redirect the user.

Create a new function that fires on the admin_init hook and listen for your action there to redirect.

```
public function init() {
    add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'create_admin_menu' ) );
    add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'do_actions' ) ); 
}

public function do_actions() {
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['actions'] ) && $_REQUEST['actions'] == 'MY_UNIQUE_ACTION_NAME' ) {
        $this->add_item();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Actually `admin_menu` menu fires before `admin_init` ;) Both actions are executed before any response is sent and both are fine for a redirect header.